# Recover the inverse after interative solution of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I have solved the linear system $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ with an iterative solver.  The problem is well-posed ($\mathbf{A}$ is invertible, $\mathbf{b} \ne \mathbf{0}$, blah blah blah).

*The question*: Is it possible to combine $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{x}$, and $\mathbf{b}$  (all known), to get the inverse $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$?

*The context*: I am optimizing a function of $\mathbf{x}$, and the parameters that I am optimizing with respect to show up in $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.  I need to know the inverse of $\mathbf{A}$ to get the derivatives, *i.e.*,
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}}{\partial p} = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \left( \frac{\partial \mathbf{b}}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial p} \mathbf{x} \right)  ,
$$
where $p$ is one of my parameters, and so on for the Hessian.  A direct solution is out of the question because the problem dimension is very large, so I can't store and re-use one of the triangular factors.  I'm not coming up with anything on my own or in my textbooks, so here I am.

Comment: official terminology on this site is yadda yadda yadda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6kRqnfsBEc

Comment: Why do you want to *invert the matrix* in the first place, when all you really need to do is to *solve a system*?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: ok then, the question then becomes, I have several $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{1} = \mathbf{b}_{1}$,  $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{2} = \mathbf{b}_{2}$, etc., where the $\mathbf{A}$'s are all the same, and I have to solve them iteratively because of the large dimension of the problem.  Is there any way to reduce computation time for the second an onward problem, after getting the solution to the first one?

Comment: Quite a number of papers were written on solving sequences of linear systems. In general, iterative solvers for sequences of systems attempt to reuse some information obtained from the previous solves in order to improve the convergence for new systems (right-hand side). You might have a look on [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/040607277). Although it's not maybe what do you look for, it might contain or be cited by a useful reference.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks!  That really helps.  My searches were missing the word "sequence".

Answer (score 0):

Each columns of the inverse is the solution to $Ax = b$ when $b = e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.

At the very least, finding $A^{-1}$ from the $x$'s would require that you choose $n$ linearly independent $b$s.  Perhaps you can optimize on which $b$'s you select.